# git clone AWS codecommit failing with 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, clone, git-clone, aws-codecommit

I am following https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-1/
and facing an issue when trying to clone the repo "wildrydes-site" I just created in CodeCommit.

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/wildrydes-site
Cloning into 'wildrydes-site_new'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/wildrydes-site/': The requested URL returned error: 403"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IAM user or role being used  has `codecommit:GitPull` permissions or you can attach the managed policy `AWSCodeCommitPowerUser` to provide more wider codecommit access.

### Approach 1 for IAM Users using Git Credentials

You need to setup IAM credentials like they mentioned in point 'e'. Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html#setting-up-gc-iam) to generate codecommit credentials for your IAM User.

The generated credentials will have a username and password with the username in the format `<your-iam-username>-at-<account id>`. Make sure to copy the password or download the credentials file. Use these username and password values when you run git clone command.

### Approach 2 for IAM roles or users.

You need to configure your IAM user aws credentials locally using `aws configure` or If you are using roles, you need to run `aws sts assume-role --role-arn <role-arn>` to assume the role after `aws configure` and generate the temporary credentials which you can export to your environment.

Once the aws credentials configuration is done, you can run below commands to use AWS CLI as your credential helper.

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

Run your `git clone` after running above commands. That should fix your issue too.